# Problems with URL shortening (Symfony)

Tags: symfony-1.4

I have a problem, I don't know if it's a routing problem. This is the adress to my symfony project:

```
http://192.168.10.10/index.php
```

And it works. When clicking on a link to module1

```
<a href="<?php echo url_for('module1/index'); ?>">module1</a>
```

the browser shortens the adress to 192.168.10.10/module1 and gives a not-found error. When I add index.php manually (so that the adress is 192.168.10.10/index.php/module1) it works and the right page is shown. Why? Where is the problem?

Comment: Can you show us your `.htaccess` file? This should work if you have `no_script_name: off` option in your `config\settings.yml`. But remember this setting can only be applied to one app in your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either set

```
no_script_name: false
```

in your `app/frontend/config/settings.yml`

Or check if your Apache has mod_rewrite enabled (assuming that you're using Apache).

Comment: Set no_script_name: false and cc. Now it works. thanks for your help!